# Can I check if action is a child action in a view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I know that I can check if an action is a child action inside a controller, store the result in `ViewBag` or elsewhere and pass this information to the view, but assuming I don't want\can't modify the controller, is there some way to check if the current action is a child action in a view alone? If yes how can I achieve it?

Comment: Never came across a need to find this. What's the use case?

Comment: @SBirthare This is a trick for the times when you need an action to work as both normal and child action (in my case I had a regular action that I need to use as a child one, but due to reasons I needed to avoid modifying the controller and keep the action usable as a regular one). When you detect the action as a child one you just clear the `Layout` value and you got yourself a legit child action. Solution like this makes more sense when you use it for AJAX requests (keep layout for non-AJAX requests, but strip it for AJAX requests).

Comment: @jahu instead of doing that, you should be returning PartialView / View depending on child/parent action state. that automatically excludes layout or includes it. you don't need `if`s in views for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `ViewContext.IsChildAction` in view.